# Learning c getting position pointer out of strtok as int

Tags: c, string, strtok

Beginner here,
somewhat confused about an exercise:
[Tutorial](http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-uebungen-teil2.html) Last one on the page (it is german). I should read HTML-Lines and print attributes and their values. The declaration of the function which should be used is given.
Two things irritate me:
1. The Line is stored in a const char string, but i would like the User to type in his desired HTML-line. It seems not to be possible to change a const variable at runtime. How can it be achieved without changing the given declaration?
2. The Tutorial wants me to give back the position of strtok-search as an integer, but I read online that this value is stored within strtok, is there a way to cast that, or get it somehow?

To solve the exercise I wrote this code, but the program crashes at runtime with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"-Message and I don't know why, could someone please explain that to me? (I probably need malloc, but for which variable?)

```
//cHowTo Uebung Teil 2 Nr. 4
//HTMLine.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//char getHTMLline ();
int getHtmlAttributes(const char *string, int start, char *attrNamem,char *attrValue); //given by Tutorial

int main(int argc, char *argv) //because i want user-input later on, if possible
{
  const char strg[]= {"<img src=\"kurt.jpg\" width=\"250\" alt=\"Kurt Kanns\" />"}; //given example line by tutorial
  char attriN[255]={0}, attriV[255]={0};
  int pos=99;
  //printf("Please type the tag for analysis.\n"); 
  //fgets(strg, 255, stdin);                
  printf("attribute\tvalue\n\n");
  do
  {
    pos =  getHtmlAttributes(strg, pos, attriN, attriV); //pos should be strtok-search-position
    printf("%s\t\t%s\n", attriN, attriV);
  } 
  while(pos!=1);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int getHtmlAttributes(const char *string, int start, char *attrNamem, char *attrValue)
{
  int i, len;
  char *ptr;
  len = strlen(string);
  char stringT[len]; //variable used to be split by strtok


  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    stringT[i]=string[i];//copy string to stringT
  if(start==99)
    ptr = strtok(stringT, "<="); //get first attribute as whole
  else
    ptr = strtok(NULL, "= "); // get following attributes
  for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
    attrNamem[i] = ptr[i];

  ptr = strtok(NULL, "\""); //get values

  for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
    attrValue[i] = ptr[i];

  if(ptr == NULL) //if search complete
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else // if search continues
  {
    return 0;
  }

}

//char getHTMLline ()
//{
//  char user_input;
//    scanf("%s", &user_input);
//    return user_input;
//}
```

Comment: run it in a debugger or throw in some printf()s to narrow down where it is crashing.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the `attrName`s and `attrValue`s you return. Go back to the tutorial page about arrays and/or `char*`-style strings and reread it :)

Comment: I thought there would have been (enough) memory reserved by using `char attriN[255]={0}, attriV[255]={0};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `strtok()` does is that if you call it with a string different to `NULL` it stores a pointer to that string internally and returns the first token. A subsequent call with `NULL` then uses that internally stored pointer to determine the next token.

Now what happens in your code is:
When you call `getHtmlAttributes()` for the first time you create a copy of the given `string` in `stringT` and pass that copy to `strtok()`. The next time you call `strtok( NULL, ... )`. And there we have two bugs:

1. your loop to copy `string()` to `stringT()` is not correct. You don't copy 
   the teminating `'\0'`. Just use `strcpy()` in such cases
2. the important one: When you call `getHtmlAttributes()` for the second time, you call `strtok( NULL, ... )` but the lifetime of the `stringT` that it has been called with originally has ended with the first call of `getHtmlAttributes()` returning, because `stringT` is a local variable that is created anew on the stack every time the function is called. You could solve that problem by either

   - declaring `static char stringT[N]` where N must be a constant (like 255), you can't use `len` (what should have been `len+1` anyway) in that case
   - creating a dynamically allocated copy of `string` by `char *stringT = strdup( string );`. Please do that only if you call `strtok( stringT, ... )` aferwards and be aware that without additional code you have a memory leak because you are not able to free that memory again.
   - what I would pefer: use `string` directly instead of `stringT`. In that case you should not declare `string` as const and create a copy of `strg` in `main()` that you pass to the function

**Edit**
I think the request "give back the position of strtok-search as an integer" means, you should return the offset of the found token in the complete string. That's quite easy to achieve, if you use the suggested solution `static char stringT[N]` from above:
As `strtok()` works on the string passed by the first call, after receiving a `ptr` different from NULL, you can calculate and return `int offset = ptr - stringT;`

**Edit 2**

*And now something completely different*

I've just read the Tutorial you have linked to (greetings from Hessen :-) ) and I think the idea is to use a new `strtok()` loop every time the function is called. That could like this:

```
int getHtmlAttributes(const char *string, int start, char *attrName, char *attrValue)
{
     char *buf;
     char *attrptr;
     char *ptr;

     // copy the substring starting at start to buf
     // you should add error checking (buf may become NULL)
     buf = strdup( string+start );

     // first step: tokenize on whitespace; we stop at the first token that contains a "="
     for( attrptr = strtok( buf, " \t" ); attrptr && (ptr = strchr( attrptr, '=' )) != NULL; attrptr = strtok( NULL, " \t" ) ) ;

    if( attrptr ) {
           // copy everything before "=" to attrName
           sprintf( attrName, "%.*s", ptr-attrptr, attrptr );
           // copy everything after "=" to attrValue
           strcpy( attrValue, ptr+1 );

           // the next start is the current start + the offset of the attr found 
           // + the length of the complete attr
           start += (attrptr - buf) + strlen( attrptr );
           free( buf );
           return start;
     } else {
           // no more attribute
           free( buf );
           return -1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copied now correctly from `string` to `stringT`. Since I am not allowed to change the declaration of the `getHtmlAttributes()`-declaration, the second time calling the function is the reason for giving back the position of strtok, which is implied by the exercise (I guess).

Comment: Thanks for your time! I ended up doing it with `start = (ptr-stringT)+strlen(ptr)+1;
    return start;`